# Uncaught SyntaxError: [undefined] is not a function

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

On my code that looks like this, my third command line throws an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Number. How and why does this happen?
I read a book called "Javascript for Kids" to program a snake game, but the code throws errors.

```
// Pass an animation function to setInterval
                var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
                  ctx.ClearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                  drawScore();
                  snake.move();
                  snake.draw();
                  apple.move();
                  drawBorder();
                }, 100);
```

The full code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Snake!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Set up canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext

    // Get the width and height in blocks
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    // Work out the width and height in blocks
    var blockSize = 10;
    var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize
    var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

    // Set score to 0
    var score = 0;

    // Draw the border
    var drawBorder = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Gray"
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, width, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
        ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
    };
    // Draw the score on the top-left corner
    var drawScore = function () {
        ctx.font = "20px Courier";
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    // Clear the interval and display Game Over text
    var gameOver = function () {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        ctx.font = "60px Courier";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillText("Game Over!", width / 2, height / 2);
    };
    // Draw a circle (using the function from Chapter 14)
      var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, math.PI * 2, false);
        if (fillCircle) {
          ctx.fill();
        } else {
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      };

      // The block constructor
      var Block = function (col, row) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
      };

      // Draw a square at the new head's location
      Block.prototype.drawSquare = function (color) {
        var x = this.col * blockSize;
        var y = this.row * blockSize;
        ctx.filStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
      };

      // Draw a circle at Apple's location
      Block.prototype.draw = function () {
        return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
      };
        // The Snake constructor
        var Snake = function () {
            this.segments = [
                new Block(7, 5),
                new Block(6, 5),
                new Block(5, 5)  
                ];

                this.direction = "right";
                this.nextDirection = "right";
            };

        // Draw a square for each segment of the snake's body
        Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
            this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
          }
        };

        // Create a new head and add it to the beggining of the snake to move the snake in its current direction
        Snake.prototype.move = function () {
          var head = this.segments[0];
          var newHead;

          this.direction = this.nextDirection;

          if (this.direction === "right") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
          } else if (this.direction === "down") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
          } else if (this.direction = "left") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
          } else if (this.direction = "right") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
          }

            if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
              gameOver();
              return;
            }

          this.segments.unshift(newHead);

          if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
            score++;
            apple.move();
          } else {
            this.segments.pop();
          }
        };

        // Check to see if the snake's new head has collided with the wall or itself
        Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
          var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
          var topCollision = (head.col === 0);
          var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
          var bottomCollision = (head.col === heightInBlocks - 1);

          var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

          var selfCollision = false

          for (var i=o; this.segments.length; i++) {
            if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
              selfCollision = true;
            }
          }

          return wallCollision || selfCollision
        };

        // Set the snake's next direction based on the keyboard
        Snake.prototype.setDirection = function (newDirection) {
          if (thisdirection === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
            return;
          } else if (thisDirection === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
            return;
          } else if (thisDirection === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
            return;
          } else if (thisDirection === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
            return;
          }

          this.nextDirection = newDirection;
        };

        // The apple constructor
        var Apple = function () {
            this.position = new Block(10, 10);
        };

        // Draw a circle at the apple's location
        Apple.prototype.draw = function () {
            this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
        };

        // Move the apple to a new random location
        Apple.prototype.move = function () {
          var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
          var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
          this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
        };

        // Create the snake and the apple objects
        var snake = new Snake();
        var apple = new Apple();

        // Pass an animation function to setInterval
        var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
          ctx.ClearRect(0, 0, width, height);
          drawScore();
          snake.move();
          snake.draw();
          apple.move();
          drawBorder();
        }, 100);

        // Convert keycodes to directions
        var directions = { 
          37: "left",
          38: "up",
          39: "right",
          40: "down"
        };

        //the keydown handler for handling direction key presses
        $("body").keydown(function (event) {
          var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
          if (newDirection !==undefined) {
            snake.setDirection(newDirection);
        }
      });                                                                                                                                 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can you help me?

An addition that is new:
My new code follows as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Snake!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Set up canvas
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // Get the width and height in blocks
    var width = canvas.width;
    var height = canvas.height;

    // Work out the width and height in blocks
    var blockSize = 10;
    var widthInBlocks = width / blockSize
    var heightInBlocks = height / blockSize;

    // Set score to 0
    var score = 0;

    // Draw the border
    var drawBorder = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = "Gray"
        ctx.fillRect(0,0, width, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(0, height - blockSize, width, blockSize);
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, blockSize, height);
        ctx.fillRect(width - blockSize, 0, blockSize, height);
    };
    // Draw the score on the top-left corner
    var drawScore = function () {
        ctx.font = "20px Courier";
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        ctx.textAlign = "left";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        ctx.fillText("Score: " + score, blockSize, blockSize);
    };
    // Clear the interval and display Game Over text
    var gameOver = function () {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        ctx.font = "60px Courier";
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
        ctx.fillText("Game Over!", width / 2, height / 2);
    };
    // Draw a circle (using the function from Chapter 14)
      var circle = function (x, y, radius, fillCircle) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, math.PI * 2, false);
        if (fillCircle) {
          ctx.fill();
        } else {
          ctx.stroke();
        }
      };

      // The block constructor
      var Block = function (col, row) {
        this.col = col;
        this.row = row;
      };

      // Draw a square at the new head's location
      Block.prototype.drawSquare = function (color) {
        var x = this.col * blockSize;
        var y = this.row * blockSize;
        ctx.filStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
      };

      // Draw a circle at Apple's location
      Block.prototype.draw = function () {
        return this.col === otherBlock.col && this.row === otherBlock.row;
      };
        // The Snake constructor
        var Snake = function () {
            this.segments = [
                new Block(7, 5),
                new Block(6, 5),
                new Block(5, 5)  
                ];

                this.direction = "right";
                this.nextDirection = "right";
            };

        // Draw a square for each segment of the snake's body
        Snake.prototype.draw = function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.segments.length; i++) {
            this.segments[i].drawSquare("Blue");
          }
        };

        // Create a new head and add it to the beggining of the snake to move the snake in its current direction
        Snake.prototype.move = function () {
          var head = this.segments[0];
          var newHead;

          this.direction = this.nextDirection;

          if (this.direction === "right") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col + 1, head.row);
          } else if (this.direction === "down") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row + 1);
          } else if (this.direction = "left") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col - 1, head.row);
          } else if (this.direction = "right") {
            newHead = new Block(head.col, head.row - 1);
          }

            if (this.checkCollision(newHead)) {
              gameOver();
              return;
            }

          this.segments.unshift(newHead);

          if (newHead.equal(apple.position)) {
            score++;
            apple.move();
          } else {
            this.segments.pop();
          }
        };

        // Check to see if the snake's new head has collided with the wall or itself
        Snake.prototype.checkCollision = function (head) {
          var leftCollision = (head.col === 0);
          var topCollision = (head.col === 0);
          var rightCollision = (head.col === widthInBlocks - 1);
          var bottomCollision = (head.col === heightInBlocks - 1);

          var wallCollision = leftCollision || topCollision || rightCollision || bottomCollision;

          var selfCollision = false

          for (var i=0; this.segments.length; i++) {
            if (head.equal(this.segments[i])) {
              selfCollision = true;
            }
          }

          return wallCollision || selfCollision
        };

        // Set the snake's next direction based on the keyboard
        Snake.prototype.setDirection = function (newDirection) {
          if (thisdirection === "up" && newDirection === "down") {
            return;
          } else if (thisDirection === "right" && newDirection === "left") {
            return;
          } else if (thisDirection === "down" && newDirection === "up") {
            return;
          } else if (thisDirection === "left" && newDirection === "right") {
            return;
          }

          this.nextDirection = newDirection;
        };

        // The apple constructor
        var Apple = function () {
            this.position = new Block(10, 10);
        };

        // Draw a circle at the apple's location
        Apple.prototype.draw = function () {
            this.position.drawCircle("LimeGreen");
        };

        // Move the apple to a new random location
        Apple.prototype.move = function () {
          var randomCol = Math.floor(Math.random() * (widthInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
          var randomRow = Math.floor(Math.random() * (heightInBlocks - 2)) + 1;
          this.position = new Block(randomCol, randomRow);
        };

        // Create the snake and the apple objects
        var snake = new Snake();
        var apple = new Apple();

        // Pass an animation function to setInterval
        var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
          drawScore();
          snake.move();
          snake.draw();
          apple.move();
          drawBorder();
        }, 100);

        // Convert keycodes to directions
        var directions = { 
          37: "left",
          38: "up",
          39: "right",
          40: "down"
        };

        //the keydown handler for handling direction key presses
        $("body").keydown(function (event) {
          var newDirection = directions[event.keyCode];
          if (newDirection !==undefined) {
            snake.setDirection(newDirection);
        }
      });                                                                                                                                 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: Your issue is from the line before, but originates from `var ctx = canvas.getContext`, which should be `var ctx = canvas.getContext()`.

Comment: @PM77-1 I am getting a Uncaught TypeError: head.equal is not a function after your suggestions, the o is not defined was changed to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Its probably in the area

```
ctx.ClearRect()
```

Because its should be

```
ctx.clearRect()
```

You added a capital c

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext
```

should be

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext();
```

and that the error is from:

```
ctx.ClearRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

since *ctx* references the *getContext* method rather than an actual canvas context.

Comment: He should also pass '2d' as the context to `getContext()`, otherwise it will return `null`, as in `ctx.getContext('2d')`. Also, `ClearRect` should be `clearRect`. The errors don't stop there, though. After you fix those, more lines keep on throwing: an undeclared `o` variable inside of a loop, a call to a method `equals` that doesn't seem to be anywhere in the code...

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett—yes, no doubt. I haven't use canvas in a while. ;-)

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett Could you please include the code so I can try it out?

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett— Could you please include the code in your next comment so I could test the code? Thanks!

Comment: @WL, I actually just found the book you're learning from, and you skipped adding the `equal` method to `Block`'s prototype. You also had some other mistakes lying around, I corrected those, check the code and compare it to yours: http://jsfiddle.net/esm4mgvw/. It's not detecting the collision when you hit an 'up' wall, but I'm sure it's a small issue somewhere in your code. Try taking a second look at your book. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, in fact it not detecting collisions up and down was just a minor mistake in your code, using `col` instead of `row`: http://jsfiddle.net/esm4mgvw/1/